# Get Index at Drag and Drop Hierarchical Datasource Telerik Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am trying to create a drag and drop between two tree list both of which is bound to a hierarchicaldatasource.

The drag and dropping is working but I can't get the drop into the right row in the datasource. It appends to the end and that's not what I want. I'm sure it's straightforward but I'm still a newbie with JS and Kendo.

Here is the code. This a prototype of my actual code so I can get the basics. Help is very much appreciated.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({  
data: [{
    text: "Furniture",
    items: [{
        text: "Tables & Chairs"
    }, {
        text: "Sofas"
    }, {
        text: "Occasional Furniture"
    }]
}, {
    text: "Decor",
    items: [{
        text: "Bed Linen"
    }, {
        text: "Curtains & Blinds"
    }, {
        text: "Carpets"
    }]
}]
});

var newDataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
data: [{
    text: "Level 1",
items: [{
    text: "Level 1a"
    }]
}]
});

var treeView2 = $("#treeView2").kendoTreeView({
dragAndDrop: true,
dataSource: newDataSource,
dataTextField: "text",

drop: function (e) {

    if (e.valid) {
      //Get what row we are on.

        console.log("TV2 : Dropped", e.sourceNode);
        var item =      $("#treeView2").data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.sourceNode);
        var data = treeView2.data();
        data.kendoTreeView.dataSource.add({
            text: item.text
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
},
dragend: function(e) {
    console.log("Drag end", e.sourceNode, e.dropPosition, e.destinationNode);
}
});


$("#treeView1").kendoTreeView({
dragAndDrop: true,
dataSource: inlineDefault,
dataTextField: "text",
drag: function (e) {

    if (!$("#treeView1").data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.sourceNode).hasChildren) {

        e.setStatusClass('k-add');

        var selectedRow = treeview.findByText(e.sourceNode.textContent);
        $("#treeView1").data("kendoTreeView").remove(selectedRow);

     } else {

                e.setStatusClass('k-denied');
      }
},
drop: function (e) {

    if (e.valid) {


        var item = $("#treeView1").data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.sourceNode);
        var data = treeView2.data();

        var treeView2DS = $("#treeView2").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource;


        var treeView1 = $("#treeView1").data("kendoTreeView");

                    //get the Data source
        treeView2DS.fetch(function(){
                    var dataItem = treeView2DS.at(0);
                    console.log(dataItem.text); // displays "Jane Doe"
                    var dataItemWhichDoesNotExist = treeView2DS.at(3);
                    console.log(dataItemWhichDoesNotExist); // displays "undefined"
                    });

        debugger;

        data.kendoTreeView.dataSource.add({
            text: item.text
        });

        var treeview = $("#treeView1").data("kendoTreeView");
                    var bar = treeview.findByText(item.text);
                    treeview.remove(bar);

      e.setValid(true);

    }
    e.preventDefault();

},
});
});
```